# HTTPS connections are generating incoming connections

Tags: firewall, ssl, https

I have a lot of records in my firewall log that are related to HTTPS traffic. For some reason incoming connections are being made to ephemeral ports and they are blocked by my firewall because these ports are closed.

```
dec 08 11:49:12 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34004 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:12 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34004 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:12 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=51 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=34004 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=25611 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=43402 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=25612 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=43402 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=233 ID=53730 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52450 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=233 ID=53731 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52450 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=57942 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=46798 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=25613 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=43402 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:24 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=57944 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=46798 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:49:39 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=232 ID=56694 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52468 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:50:14 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=57810 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52484 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:50:14 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=57811 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=52484 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:50:35 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=235 ID=42912 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=54426 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0 
dec 08 11:50:54 hostname kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp31s0 OUT= MAC=- SRC=- DST=192.168.1.129 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=233 ID=40448 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=38152 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Note that the traffic comes from non RFC1918 IPs, they have been left out of the logs here.

What could be the reason for these incoming connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... SPT=443 DPT=54426 ... **RST** URGP=0

These are not incoming connections. These are RST packets. These happen for example your client writes data to the server while the server has already shutdown the connection. It is unknown what exactly happens in your specific case though and if a proper iptables rules which allows packets for ESTABILISHED connections would let these packets pass.